# What is the default value for initial-heap-size (minimum heap size) in Java 6?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

I know that it is 4MB in Java 1.4.2. And according to:

[GC-Ergonomics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html)

The Miniumum on server-class-machines is 1/64th of the machine's physical memory.
But what is the initial heap in Java6 on Machines with 1 CPU and/or less than 2GB Memory (non server-class machines)?

Thx

Hein

Answer (score 0):

According to [Ergonomics in the 5.0 Java[tm] Virtual Machine](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/ergo5-140223.html#0.0.%20Garbage%20collector,%20heap,%20and%20runtime%20compiler|outline), for **non-server-class** machines, the default values are the same as the default values for version 1.4.2 which are:

> - initial heap size of 4 Mbyte
> - maximum heap size of 64 Mbyte

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link you have provided:

On server-class machines running either VM (client or server) with the parallel garbage collector (-XX:+UseParallelGC)

> **the initial heap size and maximum heap size have changed**

that means other settings are not changed and their default values are same as 1.4.2 for all other cases.